# MyBatis mapping nest pojo of fundamental type

Tags: mybatis, spring-mybatis

I have a POJO of type:

```
POJO {

int id;
int name;
List<Date> Dates;

}
```

Now my POJO is broken into two tables x and y, where y have dates and x have name, which are joined over the id as below:

```
select * from x
join y on x.id = y.id
```

Further now I want to select from mybatis mapper and map it to the given pojo. I am getting issue in mapping the Dates.

```
    <resultMap id="pojo" type="Pojo">
    <result property="id" column="id" javaType="Integer"/>
    <result property="name" column="name" javaType="String"/>
    <result property="Dates" column="date" javaType="ArrayList" typeHandler="org.apache.ibatis.type.DateTypeHandler"/>
</resultMap>
```

I tried using collection but I don't have any property within the Dates. How to populate the dates field ?

Comment: See this [FAQ entry](https://github.com/mybatis/mybatis-3/wiki/FAQ#how-do-i-map-a-list-of-simple-type-objects-string-integer-etc-to-a-bean-or-map-). `String` is used in the example, but the idea should be the same with `Date`. Note that, with this mapping, the `date` is used as the key to identify child elements. For example, if there are two rows with the same date, there will be only one item in the `Dates` property.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<collection property="Dates" ofType="java.util.Date">
            <result column="date" />
        </collection>
```

This worked